# HTML email template loses colours in mail

Tags: php, html, email

I created a small program in PHP which sends newsletter. It's fine when I preview the HTML email template in a web browser.  But when sent in mail it loses all the color formatting. Please help! How would I send an e-mail with full color?

Here's the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title> Newsletter</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .AA {
                font-size: 24px;
                color: #FFF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" height="373" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="13%" bgcolor="#336699">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="81%" bgcolor="#336699" class="AA"> NEWSLETTER</td>
                <td width="6%" bgcolor="#336699">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="252">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">%content%</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="center">copyright company</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: E-mail clients are notoriously bad at showing any HTML, informing us which email client is misbehaving could help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use only inline styles, most HTML clients are not advanced enough to understand `<style>` tags.

So instead of writing

```
<td width="81%" bgcolor="#336699" class="AA"> NEWSLETTER</td>
```

Writing

```
<td width="81%" bgcolor="#336699" style="font-size:24px; color:#FFF;"> NEWSLETTER</td>
```

will help.